# Proving Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem: question about a line in Extreme Value Theory: An Introduction

Tags: probability-theory, limits, statistics, weak-convergence

We want sufficient and necessary condition so that there exists $a_n > 0$ and $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $F^n(a_n x + b_n) \to G(x)$ weakly, where $G$ and $F$ are distribution functions, with $G$ being non-degenerate(i.e. pointwise convergence for every continuous point of $G$)

In the book Extreme Value Theory: An Introduction, it is said that $F^n(a_n x + b_n) \to G(x)$ weakly is equivalent to $n \log F(a_n x +b_n) \to \log G(x)$ for each continuity point $x$ of $G$ for which $0<G(x)<1$.

[image]

[image]

But I'm not sure why the equivalence holds since restricting to continuity point with $0<G(x)<1$ seems too weak.

In general, even if $F_n(x) \to G(x)$ for all continuity point of $G$ with $0<G(x)<1$, $F_n$ may not converge weakly to $G$. So why is that in this case the equivalence holds?

*de Haan, Laurens; Ferreira, Ana*, Extreme value theory. An introduction., Springer Series in Operations Research and Financial Engineering. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 0-387-23946-4/hbk). xvi, 417 p. (2006). [ZBL1101.62002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1101.62002).